# Prioritize visible content - How to get rid of this situation?

Tags: php, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am trying to optimize my website using the Google PageSpeed Insights tool. I am coming across one condition which is not getting solved my me, that is `Prioritize visible content`. Here is the snapshot:
[image: The problem image]

I have used various solutions available on the internet, still facing the same issue. You can check the website on Page Speed Insights: [Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsample1.fvita.com%2F&tab=mobile)
I am looking for a generalized solution so this situation, so that I can apply that on my other websites too.

Comment: Is there someone who help me with this, please? I am willing to write an open source solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is about how you structure the DOM of your HTML and whats shown in the screen of the users as the page is loading. To fix this you have to understand how a browser loads a page. Most browsers try to show the content as soon as possible, but if it finds a resouce that needs to be downloaded such as CSS, image or JS file, it downloads those resources and parses them before proceeding with the main HTML. So lesser it finds those the better.

There are several things you need to fix this. Here are some of the general instructions.

1. add the sections of the pages that have the relevant content in the
   top part of the HTML DOM. Example would be if your page has sidebar,
   then your HTML should be in this order :
   `<content></content><sidebar></sidebar>` rather than adding sidebar
   first.
2. Remove the render blocking codes
3. Move all JS files to the footer of the page.